# Counting possible tuples on a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l = {"A", "A", "A", "E", "D", "D", "D", "C", "B", "E", "E", "E", "D", 
  "B", "A", "D", "B", "E", "C", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
  "C", "C", "D", "D", "E"}
```

I want to count how many two letters I have namely how many AA, AB,... I have in list `l`.
I know this is equivalent of counting the tuples on list `l`, the tuples are,

```
Tuples[l // DeleteDuplicates // Sort, 2]
```

but I am not sure how to count these on `l`. As an example, there are 5 counts of AA on `l`. I wonder what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
Partition[l, 2, 1] // Counts

(*
<|{"A", "A"} -> 5, {"A", "E"} -> 1, {"E", "D"} -> 2, {"D", "D"} -> 
  3, {"D", "C"} -> 1, {"C", "B"} -> 1, {"B", "E"} -> 2, {"E", "E"} -> 
  2, {"D", "B"} -> 2, {"B", "A"} -> 1, {"A", "D"} -> 2, {"E", "C"} -> 
  1, {"C", "A"} -> 1, {"D", "A"} -> 1, {"A", "C"} -> 1, {"C", "C"} -> 
  2, {"C", "D"} -> 1, {"D", "E"} -> 1|>
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `SequenceCases` + `Counts`:

```
Counts[SequenceCases[l, {_, _}, Overlaps -> True]]
```

> <|{"A", "A"} -> 5, {"A", "E"} -> 1, {"E", "D"} -> 2, {"D", "D"} -> 
>     3, {"D", "C"} -> 1, {"C", "B"} -> 1, {"B", "E"} -> 2, {"E", "E"} -> 
>     2, {"D", "B"} -> 2, {"B", "A"} -> 1, {"A", "D"} -> 2, {"E", "C"} -> 
>     1, {"C", "A"} -> 1, {"D", "A"} -> 1, {"A", "C"} -> 1, {"C", "C"} -> 
>     2, {"C", "D"} -> 1, {"D", "E"} -> 1|>